# redirect and login or login and redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorcery

Simple question. What is preferred and why, or does it simply not matter at all?
Sorcery gem example:

```
if @user.save
  redirect_to index_path
  auto_login(@user)
```

OR

```
if @user.save
  auto_login(@user)
  redirect_to index_path
```

Just a skipment of a place, one line doesn't maybe matter that much, but what is better, safer, why or it really like of no importance?

Answer (score 0):

The order doesn't really matter much so long as you are providing valid arguments to your `redirect_to` call. `redirect_to` will throw exceptions if you don't provide valid arguments and therefore `auto_login` won't run, but you won't see errors from `redirect_to` unless you're doing something pretty wrong like passing in `nil` options or you've already called `redirect_to` in the method already.

I tend to prefer having `redirect_to` come last as it makes sense from a control flow point of view. It gives you a general sense of where Rails will take you after executing all of your code in your controller action and it will also potentially help stop you from calling `redirect_to` multiple times and causing a `DoubleRenderError`.

If you look at the [redirect_to documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) and click on the "show source" link you can see it's basically only setting variables, so you can really call it wherever you want. `redirect_to` looks similar to a `return` statement you'd see in other languages, but it does not act like one, so just keep that in mind. It's just a method that is setting some state on your controller.

Comment: And note, you can have `redirect_to` in your action multiple times, just make sure the various branches your code can take won't result in it being called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I'd log in first and redirect after.

The place you are redirecting to could depend on the logged in user. It might not in your case but it could in other cases, and it could later on in the development of your application.

For example, if the index route is changed so that it goes to a different location depending on whether a user is logged in or not, it matters a great deal whether you log in before or after redirecting. If you log in after redirecting then you'll redirect to the version of the route for users that aren't logged in.